# What are debugging methods for web development

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, user-experience

As we develop softwares, we need to run the program many times in order to see results for specific things, i.e method returns, variable values, ...etc. I am a web developer, focusing in Angularjs with Asp.net APIs development these days.

So what tools I can use to debug the code and test method returns, variables values, ...etc so that they do not require me to run/refresh the whole page, where sometimes I need to fill user forms in the UI page, or in Visual studio, running the project takes time.

So far I know in javascript debugger: console.log(var) only. 
So far, I used Chrome REST extnsion that saved my time in testing API methods resutls.

So you might answers this question by providing such Chrome extnsions, tools, editors providing debugging services.
Editors for writing codes only are not preferable.

Thank you

Comment: using developer tools in your web browser will probably be your best chance at debugging javascript. In Google Chrome and IE you press F12 to access these. Check https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging for more detail, apart from that you could try automated UI testing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/dd286681(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thank you for the UI testing information.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging   see this link